# Hibernate generates unnecessary queries

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 3.3.1.
I have a table in db (2 fields: `id`, `name`). Using Hibernate I have created a class for this table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class QTable1 implements Serializable {

    public QTable1() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) //<- modification: to comment this line
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   

}
```

After making changes I want to save them using `session.saveorUpdate` and it saves **ALL** rows, that was loaded form db. Even if they wasn't changed:

```
update table1 set name='a' where id=1
update table1 set name='b' where id=2
update table1 set name='cc' where id=3 // only this row changed
```

Code, modifying the entities:

```
final QTable1 item = (QTable1) listTable1.getSelectedValue();
if (item != null) {
    item.setName(table1Name.getText());
}
```

Transaction code:

```
final Session session = Commons.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
for (Object o : pool.getTable1List().toArray()) {
    final QTable1 item = (QTable1) o;
    session.saveOrUpdate(item);
}
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Why it saves all the data?

If I change the implementation of id (delete `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`):

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

It saves only affected rows. And that is what I expect. But without `@GeneratedValue` if I try to add new row to the table I have to specify `id` manually, that is not good.

While debugging I saw that using `@GeneratedValue` I don't have my entities in session `PersistanceContext` in `entitySnapshotsByKey` so it considers that my entities are new and must by flushed to db.

How to solve that problem?

UPDATE:

If we use `@GeneratedValue` annotation `session.saveOrUpdate(item)` generates only `update` or `insert` queries.
But if we **don't** use `@GeneratedValue` annotation `session.saveOrUpdate(item)` generates
1) `select` for table1 queries 
2) compares if the objects are equal or not
3) decide if we need to generate `update` or `insert` queries.

Now I can't understand why `@GeneratedValue` prevents quering the values.
Still I don't understand why it makes `select` queries if hibernate have a copy of selected rows in memory (`entitySnapshotsByKey`).

But I found a solvation that fits me just fine. 
All I need is just to replace `session.saveOrUpdate(item)` with `session.merge(item)`. It quaranties that `select` query will be made and the values will be compared (using `@GeneratedValue` or not). The only drawback - is the potential large number of queries.

Thanks to all. Will be glad if you help me to prevent generating `select` queries.

Comment: You are only showing us parts of your code. Can you please show the rest of the QTable1 class, the code modifying the entities, and the transaction configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected and documented behavior. `saveOrUpdate` takes a detached (with an ID) or transient entity (without an ID), and then updates it (if it's detached) or saves it (if it's transient).

`saveOrUpdate` doesn't know if some field has changed or not. It just takes an entity and writes it to the database.

You could use `merge`, which fetches the entity with the given ID from the database, and then copy all the fields from the detached entity to the attached one (and then writes the entity to the database at flush time if something has changed). But this would need a select to fetch the database and be able to compare the new state with the old one.

Comment: From what I understand, the problem is not with using `saveOrUpdate` itself, but the fact that the way keys are generate changes the way `saveOrUpdate` works.

Comment: JB Nizet, `saveOrUpdate` works just like `merge` if we don't use GeneratedValue. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in lower 3-rd version hibernate changed behaviour - it does not anymore require explicit save of loaded entities (of course, without proper documentation -  this had biten a big chunk off my ass ) if it deems that they were changed.   You may also play with unsaved value setting.

In case you like to prevent saving of persisten entities, you have to detach them from session.